# Is Covert Browser an official Tor Project application for the iPhone?

Tags: security, mobile, ios

I just bought Covert Browser for my iPhone, is this an official application from the Tor Project?

Answer (score 2):

It is not an official product by the Tor Project, and I would recommend against its use. Tor official products are not on sale. They are free of charge.